# Finalisers in Adobe Flex 3

Tags: apache-flex, finalizer

Using Adobe Flex 3, is there any way to specify a finaliser?

Comment: Why do you need a finaliser? Maybe there are other approaches to realise this.

Comment: @splash: Technically, I don't *need* a finaliser -- I can (probably) identify object lifetimes and call the code myself at the right point.  I was just hoping for an easier life...

Comment: Objects in the AVM are destroyed by the GC so you wouldn't know when (if at all) your objects were being destroyed. This is the exact same reason that .NET uses IDisposable for non-managed resources.

Comment: @Richard: Hence the 'probably' -- in practice, in this application, most objects are controlled by a displayed object and once I've removed an object from the display list I'm not going to want it again and can finalise it manually.  Alternatively, I can override parentChanged() to unhook things.  There are some objects this doesn't work for, but I'll just have to live without finalisation and code around the lack; my point in my earlier comment was that I'm not looking for an answer to a specific problem but for confirmation that I'm going to have to work around the missing language feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no concept of a finaliser/destructor in ActionScript 3, even at the AVM/bytecode level.

Answer (score 0):

Even though there isn't such a thing as a destructor/ finalizer in ActionScript per se I would consider it good practice to have a method that frees all the resources in your class, when you no longer need them.

Garbage collection only picks up objects that are no longer needed anywhere, and it uses reference counting to determine when this is the case. So as long as there are unremoved event listeners, circular dependencies (objects referencing each other), etc., you may not notice it, but your memory usage will keep increasing, and the GC never frees up these resources at all.

Therefore, you *should* have a `destroy()` or `finalize` method that:

- removes all event listeners
- calls `destroy()` or `finalize()` on nested objects
- `delete`s all strong object keys in dictionaries
- sets all object type variables to `null` (it's okay for primitive values not to be reset)

For display objects, it is usually not a bad idea to call this method when `Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE` is dispatched.